# c++ 17, is it possible to parameterize uniform initialization of vector?

Tags: c++, parameters, c++17, uniform-initialization

I have a vector of 2N lines where the second half (N lines) is basically the same as the first half but with a single character changed, e.g.:

```cpp
std::vector<std::string> tests{
      // First half of lines with '=' as separator between key and value
      "key=value",
      ...
      // Second half of lines with ' ' as separator between key and value
      "key value",
      ...
};
```

Is there a way to parameterize the separator (i.e., `=` or  ) to avoid repeating the lines during the initialization, using the uniform initialization construct? I wonder if there's a better way than creating it with a `for` loop.

By reading from [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization), it seems not to be possible.

Thanks

Comment: What is your task specifically? Do you have N lines like ```"key=value"``` and you want to construct vector of size 2N of pairs like ```{"key=value", "key"}``` and  ```{"key value", "key"}```?

Comment: Sure, I updated the example with a minimal setup (instead of a tuple/pair, a string per line). In this new example, it should be clear that the second half of lines should have the same value (string) of the first half, but with a single changed character (` ` instead of `=`, in the example as separator between `key` and `value`). Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Yeah I guess you could write an ugly macro

Comment: Are the strings known at compile-time?

Comment: Yes, the strings are known at compile-time. Thank you.

Comment: If you vote to close this question, could you please indicate in a comment the reason why? Thanks

Comment: @gc5: Reason of the close is shown when closed (and also to the ones which can close-vote, so currently 2 votes for *"Needs details or clarity"*).

Comment: Since the strings are known at compile time, it is potentially possible to write code that takes a variadic-sequence of strings, and unpack this twice: once verbatim, and once with the `=` replaced with a space (` `)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is tagged [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) and you said the strings are known at compile-time, it is technically possible to perform uniform initialization by leveraging a variadic function-template and unpacking the parameters twice, and this would produce the modified string at compile-time.

The idea, in the simplest form, is to do this:

```cpp
template <typename...Strings>
auto make_string_vector(const Strings&...strings) -> std::vector<std::string>
{
    // Unpacks the strings twice; first unmodified, second with '=' swapped with ' '
    return std::vector<std::string>{{
        strings..., to_space_string(strings)... 
    }};
};
```

Where `to_space_string` is a class that returns a string-like object, done **at compile-time**.

To do this, we need to make a simple holder that acts like a string is convertible to `std::string_view` at compile time. This is to ensure that the string we modify has its own separate lifetime and does not dangle:

```cpp
// A holder for the data so that we can convert it to a 'std::string' type
template <std::size_t N>
struct static_string {
    char data[N];
    constexpr operator std::string_view() const noexcept { 
      return std::string_view{data, N}; 
    }
};
```

Then all we need is the function that takes a compile-time string (array of `char`s), copies it into the `static_string<N>` object, and returns it:

```
// std::string_view used so that we can do this constexpr
template <std::size_t N>
constexpr auto to_space_string(const char(&string)[N]) -> static_string<N>
{
    auto storage = static_string<N>{};
    std::transform(&string[0], &string[N], &storage.data[0], [](char c){ 
        if (c == '=') { return ' '; }
        return c; 
    });
    return storage;
}
```

The last needed tweak would be for the initializer list to be a sequence of `std::string` objects, which we can do with `static_cast`s:

```cpp
template <typename...Strings>
auto make_string_vector(const Strings&...strings) -> std::vector<std::string>
{
    return std::vector<std::string>{{
        static_cast<std::string>(strings)..., 
        static_cast<std::string>(to_space_string(strings))... 
    }};
};
```

With this, code like:

```
auto vec = make_string_view("hello=world", "goodbye=world");
```

will produce a vector containing

- `hello=world`
- `goodbye=world`
- `hello world`
- `goodbye world`

<kbd>[Live Example](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/8373snvW8)</kbd>

---

**Note:**

If we didn't use a `static_string` or some equivalent and instead used `string_view` directly, the string would dangle. For example:

```
template <std::size_t N>
constexpr auto to_space_string(const char(&string)[N]) -> std::string_view
{
    char storage[N];
    std::transform(&string[0], &string[N], &storage[0], [](char c){ 
        if (c == '=') { return ' '; }
        return c; 
    });
    // dangles after being returned!
    return std::string_view{&storage[0], N};
}
```

In the above case, we return a reference to temporary storage `storage[N]`, thus causing a dangling pointer (UB). The `static_string` creates an object first whose lifetime is passed into the caller (`make_string_vector`) and then gets converted to a `std::string`.

Answer (score 1):

If only one `=` per line is allowed then following can work

```
std::vector<std::string> init_from_key_eq_val(std::initializer_list<const char *> strings)
    {
        std::vector<std::string> result;
        result.reserve(2 * strings.size());
        copy(strings.begin(), strings.end(), back_inserter(result));
        transform(strings.begin(), strings.end(), back_inserter(result),
                  [](const char* str)
                  {
                      std::string str_copy(str);
                      size_t eq_pos = str_copy.find('=');
                      str_copy[eq_pos] = ' ';
                      return str_copy;
                  });
        return result;
    }
    
    int main()
    {
        std::vector<std::string> vec = init_from_key_eq_val({"key=value"});
    }
```

From the performance point of view, it is no better than doing it with a loop though

Comment: Thank you for your answer (upvoted), however, if from the performance pov it is not better than the loop, I might use the loop. My intent was to see if there was a syntax construct that I can use in place of the loop (hopefully more clear and elegant). Although, to initialize a list of strings, I'm not looking from the performance pov but readability first.

Comment: Comparing to @Human-Compiler solution, my solution is slightly less effective because I change '=' to ' ' at runtime instead of compile time. However this operation is negligible comparing to the cost of allocating the memory for string.